# Smallest possible universal combinator

Tags: lo.logic, computability, lambda-calculus, universal-computation, combinatory-logic

I am looking for the smallest possible [universal combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#One-point_basis), measured by the number of abstractions and applications required to specify such a combinator in the [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Free_and_bound_variables). Examples of universal combinators include:

- **size 23:** λf.f(fS(KKKI))K
- **size 18:** λf.f(fS(KK))K
- **size 14:** λf.fKSK
- **size 12:** λf.fS(λxyz.x)
- **size 11:** λf.fSK

where S = λxyz.xz(yz) of **size 6** and K = λxy.x of **size 2** are the combinators of the [SK combinator calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus). The first 4 examples are described in [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03180572).

My questions are:

- Are there any universal combinators that are smaller in size?
- What is the smallest possible universal combinator?

**EDIT:** See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180263/76284, which has `λazbc.bc(a(λy.c))` (which would be of **size 8**, matching the sum of sizes of the SK basis). Does anyone know how to express S and K from this combinator?

Comment: Maybe this is of interest: https://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-1123a-text?firstview=1

Comment: What is your definition of size? Can you write it as a function?

Comment: Since 6 + 2 = 8 < 11, this makes me wonder whether {S,K} is the smallest basis of combinators measured by total size?

Comment: Your recent edit rather sounds like a (partial) answer.

Comment: How strictly are you defining "*combinator*"? Does it have to be of the form `λx*.E` where `E` is abstraction-free?

Comment: @PeterTaylor [Craig's theorem](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/a-new-proof-for-craigs-theorem/888D7384A22A933DF532B8F9115EB07F) implies that any universal combinator must be improper.

Comment: @JoshuaHerman Here, size = abstractions + applications.

Answer (score 10):

It should be noted that finding combinators with certain reduction properties is *always* difficult, and finding the smallest such combinator may easily be undecidable (for trivial reasons, as it may be undecidable to prove that a certain application of the combinator even halts).

There are several simple open questions of a similar flavor, e.g. problems #4, #6 and #10 from the [TLCA list of open problems](http://tlca.di.unito.it/opltlca/).

One thing to note is that your combinator certainly needs to have at least 2 bound variables, one of which is duplicated (as does any complete set of combinators) and one needs to be erased. This puts a lower bound of 4, I think (2 abstractions and 2 appearances of a variable), which is not so far from the upper bound of 11.

**Edit: Noam's comments and reference push the lower bound to 5! I wouldn't be surprised if the proof also requires the extra variable to appear as well, which would push us to 6.**

Comment: Actually, two variables are not enough (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2100917, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/36344/674), so this gives a slightly higher lower bound (size 5 = 3 abstractions and 2 applications).

Comment: @NoamZeilberger alright, that's a fantastic result I was not aware of!

Answer (score 8):

For your first question I believe this paper may help a bunch. It has a 6 bit combinator calculus that is also an UTM. Also it has a universal combinator that seems to have size 7 with one element given what you want. They call it Zot.
http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0508056v1.pdf

I am not sure if you can say or prove that there is a minimal combinator. The paper would suggest it would have to be at least be less than 6 bits.

Comment: Zot's combinator is actually the last one listed in the OP: λx.xSK (shared with its parent languages, Iota and Jot), which has length 11.  In the "6 bit combinator calculus" (Keraia), the "6 bits" is the size of the UTM; and it looks like it's just an encoding of the lambda calculus, not a combinator calculus (and therefore doesn't have a builtin universal combinator).

Answer (score 7):

The smallest basis is the single point combinator A = λx λy λz. x z (y (λ_.z)) of size 4 abstractions + 3 applications, and of minimal size 26 bits in the binary lambda calculus.

Minimal representations of S, K, and I are:

S = A (A (A A (A A (A A))(A (A (A A (A A)))))) A A

K = A (A A) (A (A A) A A A A A)

I = A (A (A (A A) A)) (A (A A) A)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a proof that this is the smallest possible size?

Comment: Our exhaustive search found all terms of fewer than 26 bits not to provide a basis, but the work is unpublished.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have an idea of when it will be published?

Comment: And are there other universal terms of equal size, or is it unique?

Comment: There are 2 more minimal (26 bit) universal ones: λx λy λz. y z (x (λ_.z)) and x λy λz. y (λ_.z) (x z), although they require longer expressions for S and K.