# Is there some n such that lambda calculus with only n variables is Turing-complete?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Typically in lambda calculus you have an infinite stock of variables. Could we get away with a finite set?

Comment: If I understand what you mean by "get away with", yes, since only three variables are needed to encode a complete combinator basis such as [SKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) or [BCKW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,_C,_K,_W_system).  Conversely, Richard Statman proved that two variables are not enough, as explained in [my answer here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/36344/674).

Comment: Good point. That was my intuition about it. Thanks